# Troubles with std::enable_if and std::is_arithmetic as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++14, sfinae, overloading

I am trying to implement an `OutputArchive` template class, which has a templated function `processImpl()`. That looks like this:

```
template<typename ArchiveType>
class OutputArchive {
    ...

    template<typename Type, typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<Type>>> inline
    ArchiveType& processImpl(Type&& type) {
        // Implementation
    }

    template<typename Type, typename = void> inline
    ArchiveType& processImpl(Type&& type) {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

The idea here is that if I pass in a `char`, `int`, `float`, etc to my `processImpl()` function, the first overload should be used; however, that is not the case. The second overload seems to always be used and I am completely clueless as to what I could be doing wrong. I imagine it does have something to do with the way I am using `std::enable_if` though

Comment: Try also using `std::remove_cv` and `std::remove_reference`.

Comment: I would suggest using `std::decay` instead of `std::remove...`

Comment: Neither `std::decay` or `std::remove_cv` and `std::remove_reference` did the trick. Edit: I assumed they were used as follows: `..std::is_arithmetic_v<std::decay<Type>>>`

Comment: Aside from the problem - why not use a single function with `constexpr-if`?

Comment: I'm new to SFINAE and template function overloads and still trying to wrap my mind around it. I'm not even sure I fully understand your question. Are you talking about making one of those template structs people use to, for example, check if a function exists in a class?

Comment: No, I meant to merge these two functions in one and the use `std::is_arithmetic` inside with `if constexpr (...)`. You can read about it [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if) (scroll to the middle of the page).

Comment: I see, that is actually very handy! However, there are more overloads to my template function, but I haven't tested them as of yet (Using other `std::enable_if`'s in a similar manner). So using `constexpr-if` I would have a fairly large, cluttered and ugly `if` in one template function correct?

Comment: You still can divide the logic into several, `private` functions. It'd stick with constexpr-if

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So to make it work you should use std::enable_if for 2 cases.
I will show an example for return type, but using template parameter would also work.

```
template<typename Type> inline
typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<Type>, ArchiveType&> processImpl(Type&& type) {
    // Implementation
}

template<typename Type> inline
typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic_v<Type>, ArchiveType&> processImpl(Type&& type) {
    // Implementation
}
```

Note the negation in the second case.

But as of C++17 a better way would be to use constexpr:

```
ArchiveType& processImpl(Type&& type) {
    if constexpr(std::is_arithmetic_v<type>) {
        // implementation
    } else {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

There are some problem in your code.

In no particular order

1) not an error (I suppose) but... use `typename std::enable_if<...>::type` or, starting from C++14, `std::enable_if_t<...>`; no need to use `typename` before `std::enable_if_t`

2) if you want to use `std::enable_if` in the list of parameter types, this one doesn't work

```
 template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<(test with T)>>
```

because, if the test with `T` is true, become

```
 template <typename T, void>
```

that doesn't make sense as signature for a template function.

You can SFINAE enable/disable the return value (see the Igor's or the Marek R's answers) or you can write, instead

```
 template <typename T, std::enable_if_t<(test with T)> * = nullptr>
```

that become

```
 template <typename T, void * = nullptr>
```

and make sense, as signature, and works

3) as pointed by in comments, you should use `std::remove_reference`, so

```
   template <typename Type,
             std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<
                std::remove_reference_t<Type>>> * = nullptr> inline
   ArchiveType & processImpl (Type && type)
```

now this function should intercept arithmetic values but...

4) the preceding `processImpl()`, for arithmetic values, collide with the other `processImpl()` because, in case of arithmetic values, both versions matches and the compiler can't select one over another.

I can suggest two solutions

(a) disable, through SFINAE, the second version in arithmetic cases; I mean, write the second one as follows

```
   template <typename Type,
             std::enable_if_t<false == std::is_arithmetic_v<
                std::remove_reference_t<Type>>> * = nullptr> inline
    ArchiveType & processImpl (Type && type)
```

(b) pass through an intermediate function that send an additional `int` value and receive an `int` in the arithmetic version and a `long` in the generic; I mean something as

```
   template <typename Type,
             std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<
                  std::remove_reference_t<Type>>> * = nullptr> inline
   ArchiveType & processImpl (Type && type, int)
    { /* ... */ }

   template <typename Type>
   ArchiveType & processImpl (Type && type, long)
    { /* ... */ }

   template <typename Type>
   ArchiveType & processImpl (Type && type)
    { return processImpl(type, 0); }
```

This way the arithmetic version, receiving exactly an `int`, is preferred (when enabled) over the generic version; the generic version is used otherwise.

The following is a full working C++14 example based over the (b) solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename ArchiveType>
struct OutputArchive
 {
   ArchiveType  value {};

   template <typename Type,
             std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<
                std::remove_reference_t<Type>>> * = nullptr> inline
   ArchiveType & processImpl (Type && type, int)
    {
      std::cout << "--- processImpl aritmetic: " << type << std::endl;

      return value;
    }

   template <typename Type>
   ArchiveType & processImpl (Type && type, long)
    {
      std::cout << "--- processImpl generic: " << type << std::endl;

      return value;
    }

   template <typename Type>
   ArchiveType & processImpl (Type && type)
    { return processImpl(type, 0); }
 };

int main()
 {
   OutputArchive<int>  oa;

   long  l{2l};
   oa.processImpl(l);
   oa.processImpl(3);
   oa.processImpl("abc");
 }
```

Comment: +1 for very in-depth explanation; however, Igor's response was accepted as it was short and sweet and showed a more modern approach (C++17)

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick

```
template<typename ArchiveType>
class OutputArchive {
    ...
    template<typename Type>
    inline
    typename std::enable_if_t<std::is_arithmetic_v<Type>, ArchiveType&>
    processImpl(Type type) {
        // Implementation
    }

    template<typename Type>
    inline
    typename std::enable_if_t<!std::is_arithmetic_v<Type>, ArchiveType&>
    processImpl(Type&& type) {
        // Implementation
    }
};
```

[Live sample](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XbjpVBW9yZXVTY38).